# JavaScript runtime error: NotFoundError - Metro

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

I use WinJS.Navigation.navigate to load a new page. I use this code line and it throws a strange exception from Metro library. When I comment it out, it runs well. Why?

Code:

```
WinJS.Navigation.navigate("/pages/about/about.html");
```

Exception:

```
'WWAHost.exe' (Script): Loaded 'Script Code (MSAppHost/1.0)'. 
Exception was thrown at line 5200, column 4 in ms-appx://tiponspackage/js/jquery.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError
Exception was thrown but not handled in user code at line 84, column 29 in ms-appx://tiponspackage/js/navigator.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: NotFoundError
The program '[5864] WWAHost.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
```

Comment: Are you loading any JS in about.html?

Comment: Yes, about.html includses about.js

Comment: Need to see code - the error appears to be coming from jquery so I am suspecting something in about.js is causing an error